# Using gspread python lib in python x,y

Tags: python, pythonxy

```
import gspread
```

## rest of the code.

error :

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\QSTK\Examples\MyCodes\gspread.py", line 1, in 
    import gspread**

when i try to run the code in spyder i get this error.

the code works fine in python idle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your script. You named it the same as a module you are trying to use, `gspread`, this causes a circular dependency.

Comment: For example, rename your script in file `gspread.py` to `example.py`